# Recall ruby class properties and details

Tags: ruby, function, class, irb, pry

Apologies if this has been asked before (I couldnt find it) but once I declare a class in Ruby using IRB, after several lines of additional code, is there any way of viewing a specific class and what it contains later on? I am looking to add a function to an existing class, and need to call the class in order to see what it contains? In addition, if there is no functionality in IRB, is there in PRY?

Comment: If you want to see a list of instance methods from a given class `Bike` (and not from any of its superclasses) you can use `Bike.instance_methods(false)
#=> array of instance methods of Bike`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `show-source` method in pry:

```
class Foo
  def a
  end
end

show-source Foo
```

or its shortcut `$`:

```
$ Foo
```

Outputs:

```
class Foo
  def a
  end
end
```

Comment: Cheers for that - but no such functionality in IRB?

Comment: @sdawes unfortunately, no. You'll have to use pry